# Android push notification - show the send time not the receive time

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm building a messenger app similar to Whatsapp.

There is one problem though. If the phone is turned off when the push  notification is sent and then is turned on, he will receive the push notification with time "now" even though the push notification was send 30 min ago.

This can be confusing if the notifications represents the chat message, because the receiver will think the message is sent now.
Is it possible to show the time the notifications was sent?

I know on iOS it shows the time the notifications was sent. Is it possible to replicate the same on Android?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Date & Time data to your push notification body.
Please refer below JSON data

```
data={"image":"url","nId":123,"time":"10:15:12","priority":"normal","title":"test","message":"message","type":"1"}
```

You're probably looking for **[NotificationCompat.Builder#setWhen(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#when)**. Supplying it with the time you received from JSON Data.